# What's the difference between each and individual?

Tags: meaning

> **Individual** animals take on specialized roles to ensure the entire group is fed.
>
> **Each** animals take on specialized roles to ensure the entire group is fed.

Is there any meaning difference between them? or just same?

Comment: It should be 'Each animal takes on a specialized role' meaning that every single one does so. 'Individual animals' means that certain ones have their own role; it could mean all of them, but not necessarily.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, but that should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "Each" implies every one, individually but completely. An idiomatic way of saying might be "Each and every one" of them.

"Individual" implies that there might be differences between specific animals.

For example, I could say:

"Each employee must enter through the main door", meaning, "All employees must enter through the main door."

but:

"Individual employees may enter through the door of their choosing".